# Is javax.servlet.http.HttpResponse deprecated by Java 7.0?

Tags: java

As the title goes, I cannot find class `javax.servlet.http.HttpResponse` in Oracle's official document for Java 1.7, but I can find it in Java 1.6 and lower edition.

Why?

Comment: I don't see a class `javax.servlet.http.HttpResponse` in Java 6 or 7. Do you mean `HttpServletResponse`? That's in both.

Comment: It isn't even *in* Java 7, let alone 'deprecated by' it. It wasn't in 'Java 1.6 and lower' either. You are mistaken on all points.

Answer (score 3):

It is part of JavaEE not JavaSE. See the JavaEE 6 and 7 docs below. It is not deprecated.

JavaEE 6: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html
JavaEE 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Edit: I just noticed the class name in your post. There is no `javax.servlet.http.HttpResponse`, perhaps you mean `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`. if you do see above, otherwise you'll have to figure out what class you actually need.

Comment: Well ,as you said, what I saw is just j2se document , not the j2ee.Sorry for that.